# XCode target won't quit

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a big problem.
I am currently working on a XCode project which has more targets (Apps).
So the first app starts and you are able to call the second app with the first one. The second one starts without any problems and it works great.

BUT if I am about to close the second App nothing happens, neither with right-click->quit or with the stop-button from XCode.

I have to force quit the app every time.

The first app quits normally.

I couldn't find anything in the Internet so I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers